# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors , ket-bra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question

Consider the matrix   $$
\left[
\matrix
{
0&0&-1+i \\
0&3&0 \\
-1-i&0&0    
}
\right]
$$

(a) Find the eigenvalues and normalized eigenvectors of $A$. Denote the eigenvectors of $A$ by  $|a_1\rangle$, $|a_2\rangle$,  $|a_3\rangle$. Any degenerate eigenvalues?

(b) Show that the eigenvectors  $|a_1\rangle$, $|a_2\rangle$, $|a_3\rangle$ form an orthonormal and complete basis ; 
$|a_1\rangle\langle a_1| + |a_2\rangle \langle a_2| + |a_3\rangle\langle a_3|= I$, where $I$ is the $3\times 3$ unit matrix,
 and that  $\langle a_j|a_k\rangle$ is the Kronecker delta function

(c) Find the matrix corresponding to the operator obtained from the ket-bra product of the
first eigenvector $P=|a_1\rangle\langle a_1|$. Is $P$ a projection operator?

My attempt

I have done part (a). I got the eigenvalues as $3,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}$ with corresponding eigenvectors

$(0, 1, 0)$ , $( (1-i)/\sqrt{2}, 0, 1 )$ , $( -(1-i)/\sqrt{2}, 0, 1 )$

Even after normalizing the vectors, I still can't work out part (b). I just don't get the $3\times3$ unit matrix.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to find appropriate linear combinations of $|a_2>$ and $|a_3>$ which are mutually orthogonal.

Comment: @vnx No need for that: eigenvectors belonging to different eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are mutually orthogonal. They only need to be normalized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After normalization, theory tells us that they *must be* orthonormal, since they correspond to different eigenvalues (note that you've written $\sqrt 2$ twice in your question, one of them should be $- \sqrt 2$; nevertheless, the eigenvectors are correct).

I suspect that your error stems from having used a Euclidean inner product instead of a Hermitian one (i.e. forgetting a complex conjugation). The Hermitian product to use should be

$$\langle u, v \rangle = u_1 \overline v_1 + u_2 \overline v_2 + u_3 \overline v_3 .$$

Then,

$$\left\| \left( \frac {1 - \textrm i} {\sqrt 2}, 0, 1 \right) \right\| = \sqrt {\frac {1 - \textrm i} {\sqrt 2} \cdot \overline {\frac {1 - \textrm i} {\sqrt 2}} + 0 \cdot \overline 0 + 1 \cdot \overline 1} = \sqrt 2 = \left\| \left(\frac {-1 + \textrm i} {\sqrt 2}, 0, 1 \right) \right\| .$$

Similarly, with this Hermitian product

$$\left< \left( \frac {1 - \textrm i} {\sqrt 2}, 0, 1 \right), \left( \frac {-1 + \textrm i} {\sqrt 2}, 0, 1 \right) \right> = \frac {1 - \textrm i} {\sqrt 2} \cdot \overline {\frac {-1 + \textrm i} {\sqrt 2}} + 0 \cdot \overline 0 + 1 \cdot \overline 1 = \frac {-2} 2 + 0 + 1 = 0 .$$

The other products are easily seen to be $0$.

The truth is that I should have written all these vectors vertically, this is the usual convention, but this would have made my typing more difficult. Keeping this in mind, though, place these *column* vectors one by the other to form the matrix (don't forget the normalization of the 2nd and 3rd vectors!)

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac {1 - \textrm i} 2 & \frac {-1 + \textrm i} 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} & \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \end{pmatrix} .$$

Comment: The issue was that I used the Euclidean inner product instead of the Hermitian inner product. Managed to solve the question, thanks a lot